# Examples of technical progress

Tags: production-function, technology

I'm wondering if anyone can give me some intuition about technical progress. I can buy the idea that factors improve in quality over time. So 5 workers and/or 5 machines in 1990 can produce more than the equivalent amount in 1970. But the idea of *factor specific* technical progress is more problematic.

For the production function
$Y = [\pi❨A^N N❩^\rho+❨1-\pi❩❨A^K K❩^\rho ]^{\rho^{-1}}$
what would be a technical improvement that *just* improves labor $A^N$ or *just* improved capital $A^K$? can anyone give a specific example of such a technology?

thanks